# Multiplying two- or three-dimensional arrays with broadcasting

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, memoization

### Background

> Disclaimer:  Skip if you are not interested in the background. The code is far far simpler than this.
>   The problem is more about programming than math. [Here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is the definition of multiplication with broadcasting in human readable language.

I am trying to optimize the multiplication of large n-dimensional arrays  \$A\$ and \$B\$ with shape \$(I_0,I_1,I_2, ..., I_{n-1})\$ and \$(J_0,J_1,J_2,..., J_{n-1})\$ with broadcasting, as in matlab and numpy. \$A\$ and \$B\$ are stored in row-major order in memory.

The two arrays can be multiplied with broadcasting if for each \$i\$, at least one of the following three statements is true:
Case S1: \$I_i == J_i\$, Case S2: \$I_{i} == 1\$, Case S3: \$J_{i} == 1\$.

From the shape, we can define stride. Stride is the numbers of linear index  required to step through to take one step along each dimension of the n-dimensional array.

Linear index is the index of the 1D array in memory that stores the n-dimensional array.

The stride for \$A\$, which is \$(P_1, P_2, P_3,...,P_n)\$ has the following formula: \$P_i = I_{i+1}I_{i+2}I_{i+3}...I_{n}\$ except \$P_{n} = 1\$. Similarly strides for \$B\$ is \$(Q_1, Q_2, Q_3, ... Q_n)\$.

The general form of the nested loop is:

> ```
> int cal_size(int* shape, int n){
>     int size = 1;
>     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) size*=shape[i];
> } 
> int* cal_stride(int* shape, int n){
>     int size = cal_size(shape, n);
>     int* stride = new int[n];
>     stride[0] = size/shape[0];
>     for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
>         stride[i] = stride[i-1]/shape[i];
>     }
> }
>
> int n;
>     //the number of dimensions (given)
> int I[] = {I0,I1,I2,...,I_last};
>     //shape of n-dimensional array A (given)
> int J[] = {J0,J1,J2,...,J_last};
>     //shape of n-dimensional array B (given)
> int A[cal_size(I, n)];
>     //1D array in memory that stores
>     //the n-dimensional array A in row major order
> int B[cal_size(J, n)];
>     //1D array in memory that stores
>     //the n-dimensional array B in row major order
>
>
> int* P = cal_stride(I, n);
> int* Q = cal_stride(J, n); 
> int i[n];
> int j[n];
> //The nested loop
> int Ai, Bi;
> for(int i[0] = 0; i[0] < I[0]; ++i[0]){         //Case S1
>     for(int i[1] = 0; i[1] < J[1]; ++i[1]){     //Case S2
>         for(int i[2] = 0; i[2] < I[2]; ++i[2]){ //Case S3
>         ...
>         Ai =  i[0]*P[0] //for case S1 or S3
>              +i[1]*0  //for case S2
>              +i[2]*P[2] //for case S1 or S3
>              ...
>              +i[n-1]*P[n-1]; //for case S1 or S3
>
>         //The above line converts the multi-index
>         //(i[0],i[1],i[2],...,i[n-1]) over the n-dimensional
>         //array to the index of the 1D array
>         //in memory.
>
>         Bi =  i[0]*Q[0] //for case S1 or S2
>              +i[1]*Q[1] //for case S2 or S2
>              +i[2]*0  //for case S3
>              ...
>              +i[n-1]*Q[n-1]; //for case S1 or S2
>
>         A[Ai] *= B[Bi];
> }}}}}...}
> ```

(i think i can deal with this general part with meta-programming. For now, I am just concerned with optimization.)

### Question

Is it possible to rewrite the following loop to give better performance?

Can memoization help?

I am not interested in unrolling because the actual array has 10,000+ elements.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//version 1
int main(void){
  int A[24];
  int B[12];
  int iA,iB;
  //version 1.
  //(only one version is used. but i show all versions i can think of.)
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
      for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k){
        iA = i*12 + j *4 + k*1;
        iB = 4*j + k*1;
        A[iA]*=B[iB];
        cout << iA <<"," <<iB <<endl;
      }   
    }   
  }
  //version 2.
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 12; ++j){
      iA = i*12 + j;
      iB = j;
      A[iA]*=B[iB];
      cout << iA <<"," <<iB <<endl;
    }   
  }

  //version 3
  for(int iA = 0; iA < 2*3*4; iA+=12){
    for(int iB = 0; iB < 3*4; ++iA, ++iB){
      A[iA]*=B[iB];
      cout << iA <<"," <<iB <<endl;
    }   
  }

}
```

Assembly instruction generated by gcc compiler:

[gcc godbolt of version 1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-msse4.2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVQSKPD3ADoALcmTcAcyTGISYADgQjIccANxlGSIgXAAKAG7oQcAJQBvMkiSyAggG0ATABYAutL2yAQkYCMJq7v1hs%2BgwBp9t60jJA1wB6YOUEXC50MCQHZhDgxWioAE8kaORwyIwYkEwkTgQ4ZiQAIxgPECRMVnQAdyQCKCgkLKiwfKqIAhjsVnAAa3SAM2YNV2H0XEVZKoBeJAAGSX1UJBMVgGpNkG1XPUnp2QArJAXlpFOUJABmLc3jvb1npEOZ9yQh85Wh67N7gZPF7PEAGM76ABUTiQm0uSAhZhhnyh/mBvnBZghp1hAxR%2B2BxlBFghc3sIFsLjRAF9nviaXpXFSJlMZmDvp41iYITcEStQdsgXoIOgKigUISDJSkDSyFSgAA)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

[gcc godbolt of version 3](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g62,options:'-msse4.2+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QHsDOAXATggQwFsA%2BAKFElkVQSKPD3ADoALcmTcAcyTGISYADgQjIccANxlGSIgXAAKAG7oQcAJQBvMkiSyAggG0ATABYADAF1pe2QCEjARhM3d%2BsNn0GANPvu2SO4A9MHKCLhc6GBIAMx6eu4AZui4iiAGSAC8SBaS3qhIJhYAVLElZpLa7nopaSD22bn5DYXllUgA1J0Zft0N1QkJxhlWJVmODW5DAL4J7jPJqemZOXkFKEVlFS0G3YMJEOgw2CgoIwbTSIszQAAA%3D)),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

(version 1 and 3 give same assembly code after fixing the bug)

Wait a minute... in the actual case, the shapes are not known during compliation time. Is version 1 and 3 still the same in this case?

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question in a mathematically exact way. Why can A and B have different dimensionality with different number of elements. Do you only multiply the elements or do you want a full matrix multiplication?

Comment: It is simpler than full matrix multiplication. I seriously doubt most programmer would want the formal mathematical definition. But it is here. Hopefully this won't make everyone face palm and start to throw error.

Comment: hopefully this can work with openmp without too much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

#### Bug

Version 3 does half as many multiplications than the other versions.  The problem is in the loops:

> ```
>   for(int iA = 0; iA < 2*3*4; iA+=12){
>     for(int iB = 0; iB < 3*4; ++iA, ++iB){
> ```

As you can see, you have both `iA+=12` in the outer loop and `++iA` in the inner loop.  For this version, if you are incrementing `iA` in the inner loop, you shouldn't also increment it in the outer loop.  The correct way would be:

```
  for(int iA = 0; iA < 2*3*4; ){
    for(int iB = 0; iB < 3*4; ++iA, ++iB){
```